# How can I not be breaking the law and then I am and then not again?

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

I'm not breaking any laws. Then, I keep doing what I've been doing. Suddenly, I am breaking the law. A short while later, still not alteration to my behavior, I'm not breaking any laws again.

Now, to make it harder - it's **crucial and important** that the action is something that most of us do, have done and will keep doing. There might be a few exceptions but I'd dare to say that (almost) everybody knows about it and is friends with someone who does it. It's a very common thing and one can see it pretty much everywhere and all the time.

How is it possible? What's the action?

Comment: Why does this have so many downvotes...

Comment: @FireCubez Not sure. The community was on its period, perhaps... I thought it was good when I posted but apparently, the popular vote tells otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could

> Be walking.

So

> You're simply walking along which isn't against the law...

But then

> You walk into a private property and thus are trespassing.

And then

> You walk out of the property and are no longer trespassing.

Also

> The question says that the action is a common thing which many do, well lots of people walk for enjoyment.

Comment: I sooo underestimated the community, hehe.

Answer (score 8):

It's true, this could apply to a lot of things. But the one that comes to my mind is

> You're going the speed limit, then you hit a school zone, then you're out of the school zone. If you never change speeds you'd be breaking the law through the school zone.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, anything.

> You're walking along (parallel to) a road, suddenly you're jaywalking to cross another road, and then you're fine again.
>  OR You're hunting ducks during duck season, then rabbit season is declared. And after a while it's duck season again. (Yeah, I don't know how hunting works, but I saw this... err... in a documentary).
> OR, As Beastly Gerbil points out, you could walk across private property.
>  OR You park your car on the odd side of the street (on a street that has those rules) for 3 days starting with an odd day.

etc. ad nauseam.

Answer (score 1):

> My first thought was parking in a zone with time dependent rules. (No parking 7-9am).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have a dirty mind but my first thought was

> Sleeping with someone an hour younger than you when you turn 18 (or whatever the age of consent is) and they don't for another hour.

Probably not the intended answer but likely the worst potential legal  consequences.

Comment: Well, integrering take, admittedly. The older partner can say "I was a sexual offender one but only shortly" and also "you can wait the statutory rape out". Oh boy, now I feel bad for finding it amusing. (Not condoning any sexual misconduct in any way, of course.)